# Google Apps Script Javascript string length not as expected

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function test(){
  var log=(typeof Logger=='undefined')?console:Logger;
  log.log(" ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ".length);
}
```

The code prints 127.0 in Google Apps Script, but returns 128 in Chrome browser and Nodejs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Rhino, the JS engine that Google Apps Script uses. It doesn't correctly process "soft hyphen" character `0xAD` when it's entered directly in a string; the character just gets lost. Your string contains it within "¬­®". To simplify the example,

```
"a­b".length
```

(with a soft hyphen between a and b) returns 3 in browsers but 2 in GAS.

A workaround, if you must use soft hyphen in strings, is to escape it like `"a\u00ADb"`

```
"a\u00ADb" === "a­b"
```

evaluates to `true` in browsers, and to `false` in GAS.

[This discussion](http://osdir.com/ml/java-htmlunit-general/2009-04/msg00011.html), currently offline but available from Google cache, refers to this bug.   I quote it below

---

Subject: Re: Rhino eats strange characters

Hi Richard,

for me this clearly looks like a bug in Rhino where I'm able to
reproduce it. I'll try to prepare a patch for Rhino for this problem.

Please open an issue in HtmlUnit to be sure that it doesn't get lost
(and to be sure that I've correctly identified the root cause).

Cheers,
Marc.

-- 
Web: http://www.efficient-webtesting.com
Blog: http://mguillem.wordpress.com

Richard Eggert wrote:

> I recently attempted to use HtmlUnit to load pages that have been
>   "compressed" using HTMLZip (http://www.htmlzip.com/) and found that
>   HtmlUnit horribly mangles the output. Since HTMLZip claims to work
>   properly in every major browser (and I'll take their word for it), I
>   figure this is a bug in HtmlUnit, since it is supposed to mimic the
>   behavior of "normal" browsers.
>
> Examining the source code of a page generated by HTMLZip, I found that
>   HTMLZip uses JavaScript strings that contain unprintable characters
>   without escaping them. When I replaced all the unprintable characters
>   with their corresponding \x escape sequences, HtmlUnit was able to
>   process the page. However, HtmlUnit was not able to process pages in
>   which multiple layers of HTMLZip compression had been applied.
>
> I then did an experiment in which I created a very simple ISO-8859-1
>   HTML document that contained just a SCRIPT tag that declared a variable
>   "x" that was assigned a string containing the characters 0 through 255,
>   escaping only the white space and quotation characters (to avoid syntax
>   errors). I ran it through HtmlUnit and examined the value of the "x"
>   variable. I found that every character was preserved intact EXCEPT for
>   the 0xAD character, which corresponds to the Unicode SHY "soft hyphen"
>   character in ISO-8859-1. The character was just plain missing from the
>   string!
>
> In order to narrow down where the 0xAD was getting dropped, I used a
>   ScriptPreProcessor to capture the script before it was passed to Rhino. 
>   I examined the captured script and found that the 0xAD was still present
>   in the text, which indicates to me that the character is being dropped
>   by Rhino and not by the HTML parser.
>
> Should I submit a bug report for this? Also, can anyone think of a
>   quick workaround? Off the top of my head, all I can think of would be
>   to write a ScriptPreProcessor that automatically converts the SHY
>   character to an escape sequence, but without actually parsing the
>   script, I could end up escaping characters that appear outside of string
>   literals.
>
> Rich Eggert
>   Member of Technical Staff
>   Proteus Technologies, LLC

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, it helps a lot! I don't understand why GAS use Rhino as its js runtime, it is really painful to use. It lacks a lot of modern JS features!